# How can I reset the permissions of /var?

Tags: permissions

My friend did a `chmod -R 777 /var` by mistake. Now he has his /var folder permissions like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root     4096 Dec 29 17:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root     4096 Dec 10 11:15 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root     4096 Dec 28 09:54 backups
drwxrwxrwx 22 root   root     4096 Nov  9 11:06 cache
drwxrwsrwx  2 root   whoopsie 4096 Dec 31 09:38 crash
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root     4096 Apr 23  2012 games
drwxrwxrwx 62 root   root     4096 Dec 10 11:06 lib
drwxrwsrwx  2 root   staff    4096 Apr 19  2012 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        9 Dec 29 17:36 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxrwx 19 root   root     4096 Dec 31 09:54 log
drwxrwsrwx  2 root   mail     4096 Apr 23  2012 mail
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root     4096 Apr 23  2012 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        4 Dec 29 17:36 run -> /run
drwxrwxrwx 10 root   root     4096 Jun 29  2012 spool
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root     4096 Dec 31 10:03 tmp
drwxrwsrwx 15 noufal www-data 4096 Dec 28 10:59 www
```

And I have mine as:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 Dec 29 18:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Dec 18 10:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Dec 31 10:00 backups
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Nov  7 15:03 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Dec 31 09:55 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 23  2012 games
drwxr-xr-x 74 root root     4096 Dec 29 17:30 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff    4096 Apr 19  2012 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        9 Dec 29 18:16 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Dec 31 10:00 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail     4096 Dec 31 10:39 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 23  2012 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Dec 29 18:16 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Jun 22  2012 spool
drwxrwxrwt  6 root root     4096 Dec 31 10:49 tmp
drwxrws--- 31 saji www-data 4096 Nov 27 15:05 www
```

We have similar systems. How can I reset the `/var` files and folders permission to the initial state, by not doing it individually for a file/folder.

Comment: Are you running a server? Or just desktop?

Comment: @owl, We're running Desktop.

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate): [sudo: /var/lib/sudo/navneet writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240252/sudo-var-lib-sudo-navneet-writable-by-non-owner-040777-should-be-mode-0700)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to install another machine or VM with the same version of the OS and on that machine run this two commands:

```
find / -exec stat --format "chmod %a %n" {} \; > /tmp/restoreperms.sh
find / -exec stat --format 'chown %U:%G %n' {} \; >> /tmp/restoreperms.sh
```

command 'find' finds the root directory and checks for their permissions using 'chmod' and save it to a temporary permission file.

Or this one that combines both:

```
/usr/bin/find / -exec /usr/bin/stat --format="[ ! -L {} ] && /bin/chmod %a %n" {} \; -exec /usr/bin/stat --format="/bin/chown -h %U:%G %n" {} \; > /tmp/restoreperms.sh
```

then, copy the `/tmp/restoreperms.sh` file to the machine with broken permissions:

```
scp /tmp/restoreperms.sh user@ip_address:/tmp/
```

scp securely copies the permissions stored to a temporary directory /tmp/
and execute it from there.

Comment: `/` has to be replaced with `/var`. Right?

Comment: Looks like what I had been looking for, could you please explain what the commands are doing?

Comment: When I tried `find /var -exec stat --format "chmod %a %n" {} \; > /tmp/restoreperms.sh find /var -exec stat --format 'chown %U:%G %n' {} \; >> /tmp/restoreperms.sh` I got the error
`find: paths must precede expression: find`

Comment: @saji89 added some information about what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

try this `find /var -name "*" | while read -r dir ; do echo "$dir"; stat -c %a "$dir"; done` you will be able to find the file name with the permission and write it to a file and copy the file to your friend's computer and match each filename by writing another script there.note that `chmod` has `chmod --reference=RFile file` facility so you can search for each matching file and apply the reference there.